# JSON jQuery Refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to reload data via javascript/jQuery into html div id elements every second. The initial load (ready-state) works perfectly, but in the refresh (via setInterval()) doesn't. I'm just a hobbyist programmer and would be very thankful for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php', function(json_php) {
      document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php.jq_zeitstempel;
      document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm05;
      document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm06;

      setInterval(function() {
          $.getJSON('db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php', function(json_php_refresh) {
              document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_zeitstempel;
              document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_bcm05;
              document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_bcm06;
            }


          }, 1000);

      });
  });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Have you used the Network tab to see if the repeated calls are being sent and what the response is?

Comment: It seems like you are missing a closing parenthesis for the second getJSON

`$.getJSON('db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php', function(json_php_refresh) {
        document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_zeitstempel;
        document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_bcm05;
        document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php_refresh.jq_bcm06;
      })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ex 1

In case, when you want to do the request **no matter if previous was finished or not** - you can wrap whole your logic in `setInterval`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php", function (json_php) {
            document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php.jq_zeitstempel;
            document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm05;
            document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm06;
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

### Ex 2

But if you **need to wait a second after previous was finished**, you can do kind of recursion here.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getJSON() {
        $.getJSON("db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php", function (json_php) {
            document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php.jq_zeitstempel;
            document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm05;
            document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm06;

            setTimeout(getJSON, 1000);
        });
    }

    getJSON();
});
```

#### How it works

In first example it simply calls your function every second.

In second, we wrap your function and call itself at the end of the request, after a second of waiting.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For some reason, in Ex 2 only the 'initial load' and  'first refresh' works, it does not refresh then any more.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the second example, because of a little mistake :)

Comment: Yeah, check please new version of second example

Answer (score 2):

I would create a single function instead and just call that in interval.

```
loadjSON = function() {
  $.getJSON('db/blackmagic/webscripts/jquery_gpio.php', function(json_php) {
    document.getElementById("jq_zeitstempel").innerHTML = json_php.jq_zeitstempel;
    document.getElementById("jq_bcm05").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm05;
    document.getElementById("jq_bcm06").innerHTML = json_php.jq_bcm06;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(loadjSON, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!